# How to move or reorder array elements with mongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

We have an ordered list of elements that are stored within a document using an array.

Users must be able to move the list elements to specific positions (for instance using JQuery-UI Sortable).

1. The problem is that I can find a way to update the array in mongoDB with an atomic operation. So my question is, is there any way to swap positions within an array in mongoDB **atomically**?
2. If not, my second approach is to store the elements position within the elements but I'm not sure how to create such query. Using this internal position property, I could easily swap both positions with a query. I've looked into `$position` and other modifiers but I think these only work for for query execution and not to be stored as values.
3. If this is not possible, can someone point me to an example of how I can use some kind of locking with mongoDB/node.js to perform this operations?

Thank you!

Comment: The basic ask here is can you live with locking the data to only update from one request, and therefore just blow away the current array with whatever that client has after getting the lock? It's the complexity of however you really need to handle this that is the kicker to what is the most suitable approach.

Comment: I added a feature request for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23239 . If you think its important, please leave a comment there